# Add service to Gatt Server BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I added the service successfully. However, when I checked the mGATTServer service, it was not there

```
private void setupServer() {
    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(SERVICE_UUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE
    );

    service.addCharacteristic(mCharacteristic);

    try {
        boolean isServiceAdded = mGattServer.addService(service);

        if (isServiceAdded) {
            Log.d("Service", "added service successfully");
        } else {
            Log.d("Service", "Adding service failed");
        }

        List<BluetoothGattService> services = mGattServer.getServices();

        if (services.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("Service", "No service");
        } else {
            for (BluetoothGattService service1 : services) {
                Log.d("Service", "Service UUID: " + service1.getUuid().toString());
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service1.getCharacteristics();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
                    Log.d("Characteristic", "Characteristic UUID: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error adding service: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. The [addService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer#addService(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService)) function requires permissions. Have you granted them to your application?

Comment: Btw., this is an asynchronous function (isServiceAdded is true if the request to add service has been initiated). You have to wait for the onServiceAdded callback, before your application is able to check if it is added. So you can't do this immediately after adding the service.